# How to insert @ sign with key combination (AltGr+V)?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

i am working set of queries in Winforms-Grid application.One of that is need to insert the '@' sign with key combination(AltGr+V).please anyone suggest me , is it possible or how can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Override ProcessCmdKey to capture whenever the user presses that combination of keys.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  if (keyData == Keys.V && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.RMenu)
  {
    //insert @ whereever you want it
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```